# Meaning of "direct descendant" as opposed to "indirect descendant"

Tags: meaning, kinship-terms

I know what a descendant is. A’s children, grandchildren and great<sup>*n*</sup>-grandchildren are all A’s descendants.

But what does *direct descendant* mean? It is as if some of those people are A’s **direct** descendants, but others are just his **indirect** descendants. Is *direct* redundant and only used as a rhetorical device?

Comment: I've always thought of descendent as an alternative-reality descendant.

Comment: I agree that there is no such thing as an indirect descendant....We have many (relatives) from which we are not descended...

Comment: I am of the opinion that the term  "direct descendant" is both redundant and superfluous.   To be descended from a person is to be "directly" descended from that person...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A direct descendent is someone who can trace their lineage by "child" relationships all the way back to the desired ancestor.  A non-direct descendent has to go through a "cousin" or a "by marriage" or some other non-child relationship in order to find the desired ancestor.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase *direct descendant* is usually used in contrast to *nearest descendant*, particularly with regards to inheritance.

A direct descendant is the child, grandchild, etc.

The nearest descendant may be a descendant of a subject's relative such as his brother, sister, uncle, etc.

See also [lineal descendant and collateral descendant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineal_descendant).

Answer (score 5):

As OP recognises, "indirect descendant" is meaningless in the *biological* genealogy context. But in *historical* genealogy, it can be used to mean descendants whose hereditary lineage back to A includes children born out of wedlock, or "unacknowledged" by the father. There are also cases of people claiming "indirect descent" where the lineage passes across siblings, cousins, etc., but I think this is stretching it for most of us - we'd probably say *"Well, you're not **really** a descendant, then"*.

Also, in more "metaphorical" contexts (including "inheritance" as it relates to computer programming), there's the possibility that *Class X* is primarily derived from *Class B*, but (through [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)) also happens to include *Class C* which is directly derived from A.