# Term for all relatives not in direct ancestry?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, kinship-terms

Is there a word or phrase to describe all familial relatives who are a part of the same family tree, but not either direct ancestors or direct descendants?

Included in that list would be:

- siblings
- siblings of parents (aunts/uncles)
- siblings of other ancestors (great-aunts/uncles, etc)
- children and descendants of the above (cousins, nieces/nephews, etc)

The term [collateral descendant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineal_descendant#Collateral_descendant) appears to cover a subset of that group, but not the descendants of ancestors not in the same direct line, such as aunts/uncles.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61559/meaning-of-direct-descendant-as-opposed-to-indirect-descendant

Comment: @Josh61, thanks for pointing that out.  "Indirect descendants" might work for my use case, though I suppose it requires knowledge of the root ancestor.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I know the term that covers this sort of thing. It is 'kinship terminology'.  That's a good starting point for a google search.  Here's a wiki article that discusses the field --->  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology

Comment: I've not heard a term for this. I find it hard to come up with a context where you'd need to refer to these relatives as a general class.

Comment: @Barmar, my context is within computer science, which is what probably makes this an odd request.  I have a tree of nodes with one root node and, from the perspective of a given child, I need to describe all children of the root node not in direct lineage with the given child.  I suppose I could invent a term.

Comment: Maybe something like "outlying nodes"?

Answer (score 1):

What you call "*direct ancestors or direct descendants*", I call "*immediate family*".

So to invert that, how about "*distant family*", or "*distant relatives*", or even "*peripheral family/relatives*"?

However, from a Computer Science point of view, I would probably use "*indirect descendants*" and "*indirect ancestors*". To wrap both into one word, how about "*indirect kinship*"? I wouldn't use "*indirect family*", as that could extend into step-/half-/in-law-relationships from marriages and adoptions.

Comment: "Immediate family" would never include great-great-grandparents, and [in some cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_family) it would include first-cousins; both situations being the opposite of what I am asking.  I like where you're going with "indirect" relationships, though.